# Python: Read two files simultaneously but start reading 2nd file from 2nd line

Tags: python, file

I have a code that will let me read two files line by line

```
with open("F1.txt", 'r') as File1, open("F2.txt", "r") as File2:
     for line_F1, line_F2 in zip(File1, File2):
```

I'd like to start reading File1 from first line and File2 from second line, basically I want to skip reading first line in File 2. What change do I need to make?

Comment: I think you can just add a `File2.next()` before your `for` loop to skip the first line in `File2`  before you start iterating through them.

Comment: You can't find the start of the second line without reading the first line.